# How to fix 'String index out of range' error

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a code which replaces repeating symbols in a string with a symbol and number of its repeats (like that: "aaaaggggtt" --> "a4g4t2"). But I'm getting string index out of range error((

```
seq = input()
i = 0
j = 1
v = 1
while j<=len(seq)-1:
  if seq[i] == seq[j]:
    v += 1
    i += 1
    j += 1
  elif seq[i] != seq[j]:
    seq.replace(seq[i-v:j], seq[i] + str(v))
    v = 1
    i += 1
    j += 1
print(seq)
```

line 6, in 
    if seq[i] == seq[j]:
IndexError: string index out of range

UPD: After changing len(seq) to len(seq)-1 there is no more string index error, but the code still doesn't work.
Input: aaaaggggtt
Output:aaaaggggtt (same)

Comment: If `j` is equal to `len(seq)`, then is is not a valid index into `seq` since it is too high.  Valid indices are `0` through `len(seq) - 1`.  That's a total of `len(seq)` valid indices.

Comment: Please don't code in Python like you do in C/C++. Python is a lot life-saver than you think.

Comment: I don't think you need all these counters. This is a good use-case for `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you, now there s no trouble with indexes. But the code still doesn't give the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the string, keeping a running counter and create your string as you go

```
s = 'aaaaggggtt'

res = ''
counter = 1

#Iterate over the string
for idx in range(len(s)-1):
    #If the character changes
    if s[idx] != s[idx+1]:
        #Append last character and counter, and reset it
        res += s[idx]+str(counter)
        counter = 1
    else:
        #Else increment the counter
        counter+=1

#Append the last character and it's counter
res += s[-1]+str(counter)
print(res)
```

Or you can approach this using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'aaaaggggtt'

#Count numbers and associated length in a list
res = ['{}{}'.format(model, len(list(group))) for model, group in groupby(s)]

#Convert list to string
res = ''.join(res)

print(res)
```

The output will be

```
a4g4t2
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I still want to figure out why my code doesn't work

Comment: You updated your code and you said no trouble with indexes, can you update that solution and I can check why is it still not working

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you cannot replace them in place using ` seq.replace`, also you would want to compare consecutive indexes and then replace accordingly @alyssad

Answer (score 0):

simple way:

```
str1 = 'aaaaggggtt'

set1 = set(str1)

res = ''

for i in set1:

    res+=i+str(str1.count(i))

print(res)
```