# Python count number of chars in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Input :

```
abbbbccdddaaabbbbeeff
```

Output :

```
ab4c2d3a3b4e2f2
```

I have tried like below,

```
string = 'abbbbccccd'

strList = list(string)
sum = 0

for i , s in enumerate(string):
    # print (strList[i],strList[i+1])

    if strList[i] == strList[i+1]:
        sum = sum + 1
        print(strList[i],'****',sum )

    else:
        sum = sum + 1
        print(strList[i],'****',sum )
        sum = 0
```

But unable to print the last element from list.

Is there any better way to do it without using any inbuilt functions?

Edit : I wanted to understand the logic of printing abb4c2.. that's why I mentioned without any inbuilt functions. Its ok to use inbuilt functions if the logic can be understandable.

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'String index out of range' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415342/how-to-fix-string-index-out-of-range-error)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a1b4c2d3a3b4e2f2` ?

Comment: maybe: strList[-1]

Comment: `enumerate` is also builtin fucntion

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sum is not a built-in function any more - or any function at all - if 0 is assigned to it. However, it was one before and this assignment should generally be avoided since other parts of the code might depend on sum being the built-in function.

Comment: The lookup ``strList[i+1]`` is out of bounds since `i` already enumerates to the last valid index.

Comment: @fabianegli I know.It was just a joke. Notice the smiley.

Comment: I wanted to understand the logic of printing abb4c2.. that's why I mentioned without any inbuilt functions like count or collections.Counter etc. :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Nope. I don't want to print the count if the count is 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In those problems, always keep current state (current character & current count). No need for indexes, simpler logic.

And in the end, don't forget to "flush" the current loop data, else you miss the last iteration.

My proposal:

```
s = "abbbbccdddaaabbbbeeff"

result = []

current = None
current_count = 0


for c in s:
    if current == c:
        current_count += 1
    else:
        if current_count > 1:
            result.append(str(current_count))
        current_count = 1
        current = c
        result.append(c)

# don't forget last iteration count
if current_count > 1:
    result.append(str(current_count))

print("".join(result))
```

prints:

```
ab4c2d3a3b4e2f2
```

Okay, I know `"".join(result)` invokes a built-in function, but that's the most efficient way. You don't want to append character by character to create the string from the list.

Once you proved that you're mastering such algorithms, use built-ins like `itertools.groupby` to do such jobs. It's faster and bug-free (or even better: [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56424119/6451573))

Comment: @jean-francaois-fabre If we want to count only the occurence of character we can use the counters right?

Comment: you can use `str.count` or use a dictionary (or a `collections.Counter`) to do so

Answer (score 2):

You could use `more_itertools`:

```py
from more_itertools import run_length

s = "abbbbccdddaaabbbbeeff"
result = ""
for char, num in run_length.encode(s):
    result += f"{char}{num if num != 1 else ''}"
print(result) #returns ab4c2d3a3b4e2f2
```

**EDIT:** missed the part about inbuilt functions. This uses an external library. Leaving it here because I find the initial problem very interesting.

Comment: it's ok if you ask me. The function you mentionned could be copied as source code too... that would be as good as copying my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries

```
a='abbbbccdddaaabbbbeeff'
d=dict()
for i in a:
      if i not in d:d[i]=1
      else:d[i]+=1
for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,value,sep='',end='')
```

output `a4b8c2d3e2f2`

Comment: This returns count of each alphabet **regardless** of their positions. OP is asking for count of consecutive count of alphabets :)

Comment: @nikhildr22 The Format of the output is important here

Comment: @Chris yea!! I missed tat part 